# Find the record nearest to the datetime specified

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to retrieve the data from a table which is the closest to a specified date and time for example as you can see below little bit of data about doors and if they are open and closed at a specific time. I was to retrieve the list of doors grouped by `DoorTitle` closer to a specific time. The sample data is below

```
Id    DoorTitle    Status    DateTime
1     Door_1       OPEN      2019-04-04 9:16:22
2     Door_2       CLOSED    2019-04-01 15:46:54
3     Door_3       CLOSED    2019-04-04 12:23:42
4     Door_2       OPEN      2019-04-02 23:37:02
5     Door_1       CLOSED    2019-04-04 19:56:31
```

Lets say I want to find out the status of doors if they are open or closed at `2019-04-04 23:54:55` to give me the records grouped by door title nearest to that time. I have tried this query but it does give me the records closest to this time it just randomly selects them by checking if `DateTime` is less than `2019-04-04 23:54:55`.

```
SELECT DoorTitle,Status,DateTime 
FROM Doors 
WHERE DateTime <= '2019-04-04 23:54:55'  
GROUP BY DoorTitle;
```

The results I want after running the query are the list of doors grouped by DoorTitle nearest to the date and time i.e `2019-04-04 23:54:55` specified as seen below it should return these results but the query I am using is not returning me this.

```
DoorTitle    Status    DateTime
Door_3       CLOSED    2019-04-04 12:23:42
Door_2       OPEN      2019-04-02 23:37:02
Door_1       CLOSED    2019-04-04 19:56:31
```

Let me know what sql query I can use to achieve this and how my query is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use aggregation.  Use filtering:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Doors d
WHERE d.DateTime = (SELECT MAX(d2.DateTime)
                    FROM doors d2
                    WHERE d2.DoorTitle = d.DoorTitle AND
                          d2.DateTime <= '2019-04-04 23:54:55'
                   );
```

Performance should be reasonable with an index on `doors(DoorTitle, DateTime)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT DoorTitle, Status, DateTime
FROM Doors t
WHERE 
    DateTime < '2019-04-04 23:54:55'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Doors t1
        WHERE  t1.DateTime < '2019-04-04 23:54:55' AND t1.DateTime > t.DateTime
    )
```

The `NOT EXISTS` condition ensures that there is no record closest to the target date.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate latest datetime per door then join the results with original table:

```
SELECT Doors.*
FROM (
    SELECT DoorTitle, MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM Doors
    WHERE DateTime <= '2019-04-04 23:54:55'
    GROUP BY DoorTitle
) AS sq
JOIN Doors ON sq.DoorTitle = Doors.DoorTitle AND sq.MaxDateTime = Doors.DateTime
```